# Tag merge: SaltStack

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

These two tags are for the same product:

- `salt`: https://serverfault.com/tags/salt/info
- `salt-stack`: https://serverfault.com/tags/salt-stack/info

How about a unique one: `salt-stack`?

IMO, `salt` is not a good one as it can also refer to the cryptographic salt.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me. Looped through the [salt](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/salt) questions and didn't see any related to cryptographic salt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `saltstack` instead of `salt-stack` because the product is named without the hyphen.

Comment: Verified. Correction made to the tag. Thank you!